# Prevent android app from screen recording

Tags: android, security, video-streaming

I try to protect my app from screen recording using this line in activities.

`window.setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE )`

but some apps can disable flag secure and record the videos and app content. Is there another way to protect my app from screen recording

Answer (score 2):

> but some apps can disable flag secure and record the videos and app content

AFAIK that should not be possible, except perhaps with root privileges. If a user roots their device, they can largely do whatever they want.

> Is there another way to protect my app from screen recording

No, because if it can be seen by a human, it can be seen by a camera. `FLAG_SECURE` is designed to help prevent malware from capturing the screen or from accidental capture. Nothing can prevent a user from capturing the screen if they really want to.